# how to define in java class to matches the proto blank field definition?

Tags: java, protostuff

how to define in java class to get **runtime schema** that matches the proto definition in below

```proto
message PacketHeader {
  int32 appId = 1;
  int64 uid = 2;
  int64 instanceId = 3;
  // -------------------------  4 is blank
  uint32 flags = 5;
}
```

##### a wrong case:

```java
public class PacketHeader {
  public int appId;
  public long uid;
  public long instanceId;
  // ---------------------------- how to define the blank 4 ?
  public int flags;
}
```

Comment: An answer (it works for me )  from github https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff/issues/330

Comment: more details @see https://protostuff.github.io/docs/protostuff-runtime/